# Babel: Transpile only those in a module's dependency tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have the following, a much simplified Node app:

```
index.js
foo/index.js
bar/index.js
```

where `index.js` has the following:

```
require('./foo')
```

I want to transpile `index.js` and all of its dependency tree with the results like so:

```
dist/index.js
dist/foo/index.js
```

note that a) it doesn't transpile `bar`, and b) it uses the same project structure (i.e., no bundling).

Essentially what I'm asking is: how to run `babel index.js -d dist` but transpiling *only* those that are in `index.js`'s dependency tree?

Please note that I do not want to have to manually include or exclude files to transpile, nor do I want to write code to do that (e.g., "you can use code from Browserify or Webpack to make the dependency tree and then feed it to Babel.")  I want a well supported tooling answer for this.

Comment: I don't think that is recommended. What if you have files that dynamically `require` or `require` inside functions? Its difficult to decide what to parse and what do leave out. How could babel decide what is dead code and what is used later? -- maybe write your own `grepRequire` script and put your files in a `tmp` dir and parse it from there?

Comment: @CFrei have a look at the "Static vs. dynamic, or: rules and how to break them" section here https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/

Comment: re your last sentence, see the last paragraph in my question :)

Comment: Interesting point, thanx. So for `import` babel should be able to determine unused files... I have no idea how you could solve this then...

Comment: Why?

If all your source is in a single folder it's trivial to do `babel src --out-dir dist`.  Why do you want to complicate things by excluding unused code?

Comment: @searlea because there are simply too many unconnected files such as tests/specs in the project, and in the dependencies, especially in `bower_components` and `node_modules`, some modules of which need transpiling.

Comment: Just to recap / check the requirements: you've got a mix of your own source and open-source (bower and npm modules) and you want it all under a single `dist` folder _without bundling_?  So, you actually **want** output like `dist/node_modules/left-pad/index.js`, as well as your own output?

Comment: @searlea correct :)